# mapstraction.removeMarker() function not working properly, it didn't remove marker on map

Tags: mapstraction

`mapstraction.removeMarker` didn't remove the marker on map

It doesn't throws any exception.bt its not removed on mapstraction map.

```
`mapstraction.removeMarker(markers[j]);

//I will get all markers from mapstraction map, then i want to remove all
    removeAllMarkers(mapstraction.markers);
//some of them are not removed

    function removeAllMarkers(markers){
        for(var j=0; j<markers.length; j++){
            try{
                mapstraction.removeMarker(markers[j]);
            }catch(err){
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are trying to achieve?